# Add Flask routes to a class's methods

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write a server to manage some data and serve webpages. I'd like to use Flask, the Python web framework.

I can easily set up a "static" Flask app that serves a page for *fixed* data, doing something like

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

DATA = [1, 2, 3]

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('mytemplate.html', data=DATA)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

but what I'd like is a "dynamic" app, with a Server which manages *changing data*. I'd like the Server to serve the most current data when a page is opened. So I'd like to do something like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

class Server():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    ###
    ### Other long-running methods which might update self.data
    ###

    @app.route('/') # <--- causes an error
    def index(self):
        return render_template('mytemplate.html', data=self.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server([1, 2, 3])
    ### Spawn long-running methods
    app.run()
```

However, doing this raises an error:

```
TypeError: index() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I've seen that I can achieve what I want by wrapping my methods in Flask routes *outside* the class definition, after instantiating my server, by doing this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server([1, 2, 3])
    ### Spawn long-running methods that might update s.data
    app.route('/')(s.index)
    app.run()
```

but this seems exceptionally messy! It would be so much clearer and more logical if the routes were attached to the actual methods I'd like to use to serve the pages.

So my question is: **is there a way to add Flask routes directly to methods inside a class?**

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried Flask Blueprints? Similar concept, but uses modules, not classes

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Pluggable Views ==> `http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/`

Comment: I'm confused by what's being called as *dynamic/static* app in here. What's called a *dynamic* web app commonly, has nothing to do with class based route actions.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comments. 

Please ignore the "dynamic" versus "static" adjectives if they concern you. What I'd like to do is add Flask routes to methods inside a class, instead of to functions in my `__main__` namespace.

Comment: I have a solution for this using a custom decorator and a global var to refer to an instance of the server class you assign at runtime.  Should someone re-open this question?